# HTML5 GeoLocation not working with Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, geolocation

My device is a HTC One X, browser is Chrome. I'm trying to get HTML5 GeoLocation to work in browser however I'm unable to, it works on iOS and desktop however nothing for my Android. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'>
      <title>HTML5 Test</title>
      <script src='http://cloud.keepiteasy.net/libs/modernizr.custom.89661.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='http://cloud.keepiteasy.net/libs/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </meta>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        }

        function success(position) {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lng = position.coords.longitude;

          alert(lat);
          alert(lng);
        }

        function error(err) {
          if(err.code == 1) { 
            alert("Error: Access is denied!"); 
          }else if( err.code == 2) { 
            alert("Error: Position is unavailable!"); 
          } 
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I fixed the doctype
UPDATE: I updated the error function
UPDATE: On my HTC I am still getting nothing, not even an error. On my Nexus 7 (just tried it), it works fine... WTF, hardware issue? But other GPS based apps work...

Comment: Seems a little odd to use an XHTML doctype when you're trying to do HTML5 stuff :-)

Comment: Your code works for me on my HTC One X [here](http://jsbin.com/ilijeh/1) but that's an HTML5 doctype ...

Comment: Works for me on a Nexus 7 with the broken DOCTYPE. What do you get if you replace the error handler with a real one? e.g. `        function error(err) {
          if(err.code == 1) {
            alert("Error: Access is denied!");
          }else if( err.code == 2) {
            alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
          }
        }` (nicked from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_getcurrentposition.htm))

Comment: trying this now, also changed to an html5 doc type

Comment: Did you ever get this to work on your HTC? Would love to know how!

Comment: I bet your script __is working__ but you have to wait a minute or two to actually get the message from browser. You should try it out. This is an odd bug and I guess it is a browser issue which we can do nothing with.

Comment: On my Nexus 4 I had to crank up the timeout to 20sec to get things working in Chrome. Firefox worked fine on my device.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on my HTC One X. At least you can make sure, your error function gets called, by adding a timeout:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {timeout:3000});
```

In this example, your error function gets called after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a hardware issue of some sort as no website can acquire my geolocation on my OneX, however my Nexus 7 the above code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your phone, guys. Yeah it's kinda stupid but it's the solution.